# Linq to SQL InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, database, networking

this is somewhat tricky to figure out I think, perhaps I am missing something.
I am a newbie trying to rig a database mapped via Linq-to-SQL to my server. There is a function called by clients which retrieves UserAccount from the database:

```
public static explicit operator Dictionary<byte, object>(UserAccount a)
    {
        Dictionary<byte, object>  d = new Dictionary<byte, object>();
        d.Add(0, a.AuthenticationDatas.Username);
        int charCount = a.Characters.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
        {
            d.Add((byte)(i + 1), (Dictionary<byte, object>)a.Characters[i]);
        }
        return d;
    }
```

What this actually does is convert a UserAccount type to my server datatype of Dictionary. UserAccount itself is retrieved from database then converted via this function.

However when I run this function, I get InvalidCastException on line:

`int charCount = a.Characters.Count;`

Moreover, when VS breakpoints @ this line, I can wait a few seconds and proceed and the excpetion will be gone! It retrieves Characters.Count correctly after that.

Here is my Characters mapping:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="UserAccount_Character", Storage="_CharactersTBs", ThisKey="UID", OtherKey="UID")]
    public EntitySet<Character> Characters
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Characters;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Characters.Assign(value);
        }
    }
```

I believe whats happening is that request is somehow executed on another thread then the one that interacts with database, and it errors out before database can actually retrieve Characters table. I am not quite sure...

Does anyone know what the problem might be and how can I syncronize it (without adding some gimp delay)?

**EDIT:**

Ok I narrowed down the problem. It has nothing to do with different threads networking or what not... Its just me being stupid. Here is a simple databse query which throws InvalidCastException @ line **int count = UA.Characters.Count;**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {           

        IEnumerable<UserAccount> query = from p in PBZGdb.Instance.AuthenticationDatas
                                         where p.Username == "Misha" && p.Password == "123"
                                         select p.UserAccount;
        UserAccount UA = query.ElementAt(0);
        int count = UA.Characters.Count;
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

(p.s.) UA is NOT null it indeed finds a correct instance of userAccount and it has 2 Characters. If I wait few seconds and try again exception goes away..
What am I doing wrong? This is the first time I really use a database in VS please help! :)

Comment: Provide the exact message of the exception.

Comment: Strange, I suspect that `(byte)(i + 1)` could throw the exception though.

Comment: Are you sure it's on this line `int charCount = a.Characters.Count;`? Have you run it in debug or release mode? Due to optimizations which happen in release mode the debugger can get a bit confused sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey just want anyone having the same problem know, I figured it out. What happened was I manualy **renamed** LINQ .dbml file when I added it to my project after it was geneerated by sqlmetal. And of course I did it inconsistently (it was renamed in designer but not in its .cs file). I just re-generated a new .dbml file with sqlmetal with a correct name  this time and everything works like butter!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running in to a problem with the deferred execution of the EntitySet. A simple way to check this and potentially work around it will be to try calling the `.Count()` method, instead of accessing the `.Count` property.

You could have a look in the debugger as soon as you hit that line, and look at the value of `a.Characters.IsDeferred` also.

---

**edit**

Another thing you could try would be to force execution of the query by implicitly calling it's `.GetEnumerator()` (and associated `.MoveNext()`) by replacing your loop with a `foreach`:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var character in a.Characters)
{
    d.Add( /* ... */ );
    ++i;
}
```

---

**double edit**

removed commentary about

```
d.Add((byte)(i + 1), (Dictionary<byte, object>)a.Characters[i]);
```

after clarification in the comments below

Comment: I have also checked IsDeferred, it says true. But I am not too sure what this property means?

Comment: If `.IsDeferred` is true, then the query hasn't actually executed (or finished executing) yet. Also, are you certain that you can cast from type `Character` to type `Dictionary<byte, object>`? That's what seems to be happening on line 8 of your first code block: `d.Add((byte)(i + 1), (Dictionary<byte, object>)a.Characters[i]);`. This is setting the `object` in your `d` which is a `Dictionary<byte, object>` to be _another_ `Dictionary<byte, object>`. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: I have tried using .Count() I receive the exact same exception "Specified cast is not valid." If I wait few seconds then click "Resume" it runs fine... I think its not pausing the thread that is requesting it..

Comment: hey rejj thanks for the help.. Yeah my Characters cast to Dictionary<byte, object> no problem since I also overload cast operator there. I dont know if thats the best way of doing it, but it works and I dont need to manually serialize it. But thats not whats causing the problem... I have tried adding "while (a.Characters.IsDeferred) Thread.Sleep(10);" but that didnt work either. The IsDeferred was always true and it just hang on that point. However if I place breakpoint there and wait few seconds, IsDeferred sets to false, and .Count works properly - everything sends to client no error!

Comment: well now it highlighted "a.Characters" in "foreach (var character in a.Characters)" and gave exactly same exception  "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: perhaps if I can move this operation somehow onto a main thread it wouldn't cause this exception?

Comment: nevermind see my edit in main post please, the problem (I think) is much more obvious here